# Keyboard pushes UIScrollView content out of screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitabbar, ios-keyboard-extension

I've been struggling with this keyboard and scrollview issue for quite sometime now. I'm trying to make a chat room similar to What'sApp and iMessage. I have UITabBar as a root view controller. For the chat room view I have a toolbar at the bottom that contains UITextView and UIButton the issue is that when the keyboard is presented it pushes the content view out of the screen and I can't see about 1/5 of the top of the content view. I tried playing with the numbers and still can't get it to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
   NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
   CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
   // the hardcoded 49 is the height of the UITabBar at the bottom below the input toolbar
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake((-keyboardSize.height+49), 0.0, (keyboardSize.height-49), 0.0);
   self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
   self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your app might not need or want this behavior.
//    CGRect aaRect = self.view.frame;
//    aaRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
//    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aaRect, self.activeTextView.frame.origin)) {
//        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.activeTextView.frame animated:NO];
//    }

   CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom);
   [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:true];


   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];

}


- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
   self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

   [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem long time ago. My solution is to listen keyboard frame did change notification(because different keyboard has different frame). And I think it is easier to adjust the frame of scroll view rather than content offset.